# Override Permalink and Display Post Data Outside Wordpress Directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to pull a blog post and display on my custom `single.php` page that lives outside the Wordpress folder.

I have an `index.php` that page pulls a list of my most recent pages, however, clicking the permalink sends me nowhere. The permalink *thinks* it is in the Wordpress folder, so the link is relative to that.

I just want the index.php permalinks, when clicked, take the user to `single.php` outside my blog folder and display that post.

Here is what I have so far, but again, I don't know how to get he permalinks to send the user to my `single.php` page

My folder structure to help you visualize my layout

```
+ /blog/
    - All the standard wordpress stuff in this folder
- index.php (shows recent)
- single.php (where I want the user to go)
```

**single.php**

```
<?php include_once('_header.php');
require_once(constant('ROOT') . '/blog/wp-load.php'); 
 ?>   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php 
                if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'content-single', get_post_format() );
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                        comments_template();
                    endif;
                endwhile; endif; 
            ?>
        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
    <hr/>
<?php include_once('_footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post_type_link filter to change permalinks.

something like:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_links')

function custom_links($post_link, $post) {
    if (some conditions of $post) {
        str_replace("what you want to replace", "it's replacement", $post_link)
    }
return $postlink;
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/